# Is it possible to put CSS @media rules inline?

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I need to dynamically load banner images into a HTML5 app and would like a couple of different versions to suit the screen widths. I can't correctly determine the phone's screen width, so the only way I can think of doing this is to add background images of a div and use @media to determine the screen width and display the correct image.

For example:

```
 <span style="background-image:particular_ad.png; @media (max-width:300px){background-image:particular_ad_small.png;}"></span>
```

Is this possible, or does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Disappointed with the answers? See [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline#comment49363541_9808297). It may help.

Comment: 2023: For the OP's original issue (dynamically swapping image assets), use the `<picture>` element, which is way more clean/elegant. Inline media queries, if possible, would be nice although would serve other use cases.

Comment: if working on a .cshtml file, razor view engine will raise errors for the @ character. to bypass razor, simply use double @@, for example "@@media print {
        html, body {
            height: 99% !important;    
        }
    }"

Answer (score 374, accepted):

`@media` at-rules and media queries cannot exist in inline style attributes as they can only contain `property: value` declarations. As [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/#syntax) puts it:

> The value of the style attribute must match the syntax of the contents of a CSS [declaration block](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#rule-sets)

The only way to apply styles to one specific element only in certain media is with a separate rule in your stylesheet (be it linked externally or internally in a `<style>` element), which means you'll need to come up with a selector for it. You can grab one [using your browser's dev tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65832064/web-developer-mode-in-chrome-or-firefox-how-to-get-an-objects-css-full-selecto/65841636#65841636), or figure out a class and/or ID combination that isolates this element:

```css
#myelement { background-image: url(particular_ad.png); }

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    #myelement { background-image: url(particular_ad_small.png); }
}
```

If you're unable to find a selector that will reliably match this element alone due to the nature of your page, you can use a custom property, provided you don't need to worry about specificity [or Internet Explorer](https://caniuse.com/css-variables):

```css
:root { --particular-ad: url(particular_ad.png); }

@media (max-width: 300px) {
    :root { --particular-ad: url(particular_ad_small.png); }
}
```

```html
<span style="background-image: var(--particular-ad);"></span>
```

Comment: You can also just put in a `<style>` tag in your HTML as well. This is a necessary approach for the case where the `background-image` is dynamically pulled from a database. Obviously in the external stylesheet isn't the right place for that.

Comment: @Jakobud: Yeah, it doesn't matter where the stylesheet is located but the point is that you can only do this in CSS, not an inline style attribute.

Comment: Note to future explorers that the `<script>` tag is often stripped by email clients when an email is forwarded, so people tend towards using in-line styles for emails. And this means no media queries. I'm currently searching for the best practices for this situation, but just a friendly heads-up.

Comment: Don't forget to set max-width in `em`s, not in `px`.  That way it will still work sensibly when you zoom.

Comment: Oddly, the [declaration list](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-syntax-3/#declaration-list-diagram) railroad diagram shows that at rules can appear in declaration lists.

Comment: @Mike Samuel: I believe that was originally there to account for `@page` at-rules. Today the css-nesting spec takes full advantage of this with the [`@nest` at-rule](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-nesting-1/#at-nest).

Answer (score 179):

**Problem**

No, Media Queries cannot be used in this way

```
<span style="@media (...) { ... }"></span>
```

**Solution**

But if you want provided a specific behavior usable on the fly AND responsive, you can use the `style` markup and not the attribute.

e.i.

```
<style scoped>
.on-the-fly-behavior {
    background-image: url('particular_ad.png'); 
}
@media (max-width: 300px) {
    .on-the-fly-behavior {
        background-image: url('particular_ad_small.png');
    }
}
</style>
<span class="on-the-fly-behavior"></span>
```

[See the code working in live on CodePen](http://codepen.io/Haeresis/pen/KwooLd)

In my Blog for example, I inject a `<style>` markup in `<head>` just after `<link>` declaration for CSS and it's contain the content of a textarea provided beside of real content textarea for create extra-class on the fly when I wrote an artitle.

Note : the `scoped` attribute is a part of HTML5 specification. If you do not use it, the validator will blame you but browsers currently not support the real purpose : scoped the content of `<style>` only on immediatly parent element and that element's child elements. Scoped is not mandatory if the `<style>` element is in `<head>` markup.

---

UPDATE: I advice to always use rules in the mobile first way so previous code should be:

```
<style scoped>
/* 0 to 299 */
.on-the-fly-behavior {
    background-image: url('particular_ad_small.png'); 
}
/* 300 to X */
@media (min-width: 300px) { /* or 301 if you want really the same as previously.  */
    .on-the-fly-behavior {   
        background-image: url('particular_ad.png');
    }
}
</style>
<span class="on-the-fly-behavior"></span>
```

Comment: This is a better answer than the accepted answer because it allows you to dynamically change the `background-image` when the page loads.

Comment: I like this answer, too bad support for scoped is currently very limited.

Comment: While scoped seems great in principle, Chrome removed their preliminary support a few versions back and now only Firefox has any support whatsoever.

Comment: Scoped is just used to not allow `.on-the-fly-behavior` to be used anywere but if the word is « ignore » by some navigator is not a problem. <style> may be used in <body> in all navigator, it's work. It's just a w3c validation requirement.

Comment: Although `scoped` is a brilliant solution it is not officially supported by any browser. Hopefully that will change soon.

Comment: according to https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/b/ separate style tags are not supported in Gmail. do you have any suggestion about how to use media queries in html emails?

Comment: This is an other question, because the main goal of an Email is to be reading by a Client Email and many Client Email do not support embedding `<style>`, or `media queries` or all HTML/CSS feature. So actually the problem is more bigger than that. I only know you are able to create email displayed in same way on all Client Email (Gmail included) with only HTML4 and CSS2 feature (with some Outlook hack), but there is no Media Queries in this case.

Comment: Guys, don't use "scoped" on <style>, it's deprecated.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_scoped.asp

Comment: Didn't `scoped` depreciate? https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/552

Answer (score 18):

Yes, you can write media query in inline-css if you are using a picture tag. For different device sizes you can get different images.

```
<picture>
    <source media="(min-width: 650px)" srcset="img_pink_flowers.jpg">
    <source media="(min-width: 465px)" srcset="img_white_flower.jpg">
    <img src="img_orange_flowers.jpg" alt="Flowers" style="width:auto;">
</picture>
```

Comment: This does not apply to CSS background-image: url()

Comment: If I understand well, this does not change the CSS based on viewport size, it changes the picture. So the CSS and layout will still be the same, but the op asked to use CSS media rules.

Comment: IMHO, this should be the top answer and is exactly the solution for the OP's use case: swapping image assets based on viewport conditions. The `<picture>` element not has broad browser support. "Inline media queries" happened to takeover the discussion all of these years because at the time, that was presumed the most efficient way (if possible) to achieve this. It would still be nice to have inline @media support, anyhow.

Answer (score 16):

Inline styles cannot currently contain anything other than declarations (`property: value` pairs).

You can use `style` elements with appropriate `media` attributes in `head` section of your document.

Answer (score 9):

If you are using [Bootstrap Responsive Utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) or similar alternative that allows to hide / show divs depending on the break points, it may be possible to use several elements and show the most appropriate. i.e.

```
 <span class="hidden-xs" style="background: url(particular_ad.png)"></span>
 <span class="visible-xs" style="background: url(particular_ad_small.png)"></span>
```

Comment: Beautiful workaround--hide div, show div based on media query--the only drawback I see is it will still load both images so you'd be sending both to the client.

Comment: Duplicate content is not a good thing for maintenance or SEO.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a false friend! I thought about this solution too, but we want smaller picture to serve to small devices and to save bytes to download. This technique does exactly the opposite

Answer (score 9):

[Hey I just wrote it.](http://codepen.io/Grawl/pen/LbbEEW)

Now you can use `<div style="color: red; @media (max-width: 200px) { color: green }">` or so.

Enjoy.

Comment: i up voted this, since it seemed to work back then, but it isn't. #sad

Comment: @honk31 it world only for one at-rule

Answer (score 8):

Media Queries in style-Attributes are not possible right now.
But if you have to set this dynamically via Javascript.
You could insert that rule via JS aswell.

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("@media only screen and (max-width : 300px) { span { background-image:particular_ad_small.png; } }","");
```

This is as if the style was there in the stylesheet. So be aware of specificity.

Comment: any ideas when it will be possible?

Comment: I don't think it will be. But I am not aware of all the things the workinggroups are doing.

Comment: JavaScript cannot be used in email — client support for it is inadvisable and rare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3054315/211327

Answer (score 7):

I tried to test this and it did not seem to work but I'm curious why Apple is using it.  I was just on https://linkmaker.itunes.apple.com/us/ and noticed in the generated code it provides if you select the 'Large Button' radio button, they are using an inline media query.

```
<a href="#" 
    target="itunes_store" 
    style="
        display:inline-block;
        overflow:hidden;
        background:url(#.png) no-repeat;
        width:135px;
        height:40px;
        @media only screen{
            background-image:url(#);
        }
"></a>
```

*note: added line-breaks for readability, original generated code is minified*

Comment: I would like to know why/how Apple is using that also

Comment: Quoted code no longer exists at the given link (at least for me; perhaps I get different content due to being outside the US). Besides, this really seems more like a separate question that an answer.

Comment: I submitted a bug report and I believe they have since removed it. http://itunesaffiliate.phgsupport.com/hc/en-us/requests/14201

Answer (score 6):

A Javascript solution to the OP's specific issue (responsive images), using **window.matchMedia**:

Demo color codes:

1. desktop for red colour text
2. tablet for green colour text
3. mobile for blue colour text

```js
//isat_style_media_query_for_desktop_mobile_tablets
var tablets = window.matchMedia("(max-width:  768px)");//for tablet devices
var mobiles = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 480px)");//for mobile devices
var desktops = window.matchMedia("(min-width: 992px)");//for desktop devices



isat_find_device_tablets(tablets);//apply style for tablets
isat_find_device_mobile(mobiles);//apply style for mobiles
isat_find_device_desktops(desktops);//apply style for desktops
// isat_find_device_desktops(desktops,tablets,mobiles);// Call listener function at run time
tablets.addListener(isat_find_device_tablets);//listen untill detect tablet screen size
desktops.addListener(isat_find_device_desktops);//listen untill detect desktop screen size
mobiles.addListener(isat_find_device_mobile);//listen untill detect mobile devices
// desktops.addListener(isat_find_device_desktops);

 // Attach listener function on state changes

function isat_find_device_mobile(mob)
{
  
// isat mobile style here
var daynight=document.getElementById("daynight");
daynight.style.color="blue";

// isat mobile style here

}

function isat_find_device_desktops(des)
{

// isat mobile style here

var daynight=document.getElementById("daynight");
daynight.style.color="red";
 
//  isat mobile style here
}

function isat_find_device_tablets(tab)
{

// isat mobile style here
var daynight=document.getElementById("daynight");
daynight.style.color="green";

//  isat mobile style here
}


//isat_style_media_query_for_desktop_mobile_tablets
```

```html
    <div id="daynight">tricky style for mobile,desktop and tablet</div>
```

Comment: This is possibly a viable answer but I would not say "yes you can do it" because the OP did not ask for a JavaScript solution and instead was asking for a pure CSS solution. What the OP is wanting to do is not possible, but this is a potential workaround depending on the scenario.

Comment: JavaScript cannot be used in email — client support for it is inadvisable and rare: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3054315/211327

Comment: What happens between 768px and 992px with this code?

Comment: Difficult to upvote any "Yes" answer that relies on Javascript.

Answer (score 4):

You can use image-set()

```
<div style="
  background-image: url(icon1x.png);
  background-image: -webkit-image-set(  
    url(icon1x.png) 1x,  
    url(icon2x.png) 2x);  
  background-image: image-set(  
    url(icon1x.png) 1x,  
    url(icon2x.png) 2x);">
```

Comment: Note that this is [only supported in Webkit-based browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=image-set) right now.

Comment: This doesn't work based on size (as outlined in the question) but on the zoom factor, so you might get the picture for small screens on a 27“ 2560x1440 screen. That might be what you want - or maybe not.

Comment: 2022 update: Nearly universally supported, browser-wise, usually with the `-webkit-` prefix (no prefix in Firefox). Not sure how many email clients will allow this technique (I am almost certain most sanitize CSS to some degree)

Comment: This is good for scaling a single asset, however OP's use case was actually _changing_ assets, which is what the `<picture>` element is good for.

Answer (score 3):

Inline media queries are possible by using something like [Breakpoint](https://github.com/at-import/breakpoint) for Sass

This blog post does a good job explaining how inline media queries are more manageable than separate blocks: [There Is No Breakpoint](http://seesparkbox.com/foundry/there_is_no_breakpoint)

Related to inline media queries is the idea of "element queries", a few interesting reads are:

1. [Thoughts on Media Queries for Elements](http://www.jonathantneal.com/blog/thoughts-on-media-queries-for-elements/)
2. [Media Queries are a Hack](http://ianstormtaylor.com/media-queries-are-a-hack/)
3. [Media Queries Are Not The Answer: Element Query Polyfill](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/06/25/media-queries-are-not-the-answer-element-query-polyfill/)
4. [if else blocks](http://gridstylesheets.org/guides/ifelse/)

Answer (score 1):

if you add the rule to the print.css file you don't have to use @media.

I uncluded it in the smarty foreach i use to give some elements a background color.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>
  document.styleSheets[3].insertRule(" #caldiv_<?smarty $item.calendar_id ?> { border-color:<?smarty $item.color ?> }", 1);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's crazy they didn't think of media queries at HTML level, as obviously style css gets loaded after html, it's a huge disadvantage to inlining style inside html.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, this is quite possible but only as using javascript event attributes in HTML elements. Here you have to keep in mind that not every html tag element could fire every js event, which can listen for changes to the DOM, such as **onresize** or execute js code, when DOM is loaded, as **onload** event does. In the example above I use **body** and **img** tags as they are capable to fire **img** only **onload** event, body tag both **onload** and **onresize**. Depending on the event, you could choose the approach to resolve your issue, as using the code from the examples.

Using a **body** tag:

```
<body onload="
const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
function screenTest(e) {
 if (e.matches) {
 /* the viewport is 600 pixels wide or less */
  console.log('This is a narrow screen — 600px wide or less.');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
 } else {
 /* the viewport is more than 600 pixels wide */
  console.log('This is a wide screen — more than 600px wide.');
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'aquamarine';
 }
}
mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', screenTest);
" onresize="
if (document.documentElement.offsetWidth <= 600) {
/* the viewport is 600 pixels wide or less */
console.log('This is a narrow screen — 600px wide or less.');
document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
} else {
/* the viewport is more than 600 pixels wide */
 console.log('This is a wide screen — more than 600px wide.');
 document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'aquamarine';
}
"><!-- Some other code goes here --></body>
```

Using **img** tag:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mNkYPhfDwAChwGA60e6kgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" 
width="100%" style="width: 100vw; height: 1px;" 
alt="" height="1"  
onload="
   const mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('(max-width: 600px)');
   function screenTest(e) {
     if (e.matches) {
        /* the viewport is 600 pixels wide or less */
        console.log('This is a narrow screen — 600px wide or less.');
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'pink';
     } else {
        /* the viewport is more than 600 pixels wide */
        console.log('This is a wide screen — more than 600px wide.');
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = 'aquamarine';
     }
   }
   mediaQueryList.addEventListener('change', screenTest);
" />
```

You should also keep in mind that if you decide to use this way of embedding mediaquery css in an HTML letter, it may not pass through the blacklists of mail servers, which in most cases cut such javascript events. But for the purposes of some ajax or banner, some dynamic application, this approach should face no problem.