# Edit CSS media queries with JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to set the background size via JS. This is my current CSS code that does what I need (set size % seamlessly based on orientation)

```
background-size: 50%;
@media all and (orientation:landscape) {
    background-size: auto 50%;
}
```

I would need to change both instances of the 50% value in above's code. Right now I have this

```
element.css("background-size", foo.toFixed(0) + '%');
```

This works but discards the media query. How can this be solved?

Comment: define a class/id. set properties of the class/id.

Comment: It is impossible to do this with jQuery's `css` function, because it works by setting inline `style` properties. [Media queries don't work with inline styles.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline)

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies things

Answer (score 1):

If you're just checking for orientation changes you could use:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', doSomethingOnOrientationChange)
```

but if you actually want to check for media queries being triggered you can use [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia) to listen for media query events:

```
if (matchMedia) {
    var mm = window.matchMedia("(orientation:landscape)");
    mm.addListener(onMatchedMedia);
    onMatchedMedia(mm);
}
function onMatchedMedia(mm) {
    if(mm.matches){
        el.style.backgroundSize = 'auto ' + foo.toFixed(0) + '%';
    } else {
        el.style.backgroundSize = foo.toFixed(0) + '%';
    }
}
```

Here's a demo using `max-width`: 
http://jsfiddle.net/wxgs9g9s/

Answer (score 0):

To add a condition to check whether the window size is landscape, you could use:

```
if(window.innerHeight < window.innerWidth){
    element.css("background-size", foo.toFixed(0) + '%');
}
```

If you're using this for mobile development, I'd take a look at the jQuery mobile library.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4917664/detect-viewport-orientation-if-orientation-is-portrait-display-alert-message-ad)