# how to give @media query to my inline style?

Tags: html, css

i am making a responsive site and using media query for that but, i stuck with one problem where i had given inline style. and now i want to change that style for different size of screen. how it can be done? here is my code.

```
<table class="edu_table" style="width:500px;margin-right:400px;margin-bottom:30px;">
```

in style i had given width=500px; i want it 700px for

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
}
```

1920px size screen.please give solution for it or give other way to do this thing.i am using edu_table class many places...and i want width=700px; for screen size 1920px and for particular place.

Comment: Why do you even use inline style? Move that style to a css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you want, put this in a css file or at be bottom of the `<head>`. Though the width should always be at 700px because you set them max-width. At the moment it is everything to a max-width of 1920px, everything above will get the 500px.

```
.edu_table{
     width: 500px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .edu_table{
         width: 700px;
         margin-right: 400px;
         margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}
```

Comment: i am using edu_table class many places...and i want width=700px; for screen size 1920px and for particular place.

Comment: no problem, you can give an element multiple classes or a different one, you can name the css above something like `.edu_table--main` and give that particular table `class="edu_table--main"`

Answer (score 2):

```
<table class="edu_table"></table>
```

remove inline style

```
 .edu_table{
         width:500px;
         margin-right:400px;
         margin-bottom:30px;
    }
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
    .edu_table{
         width:700px;
    }
}
```

if you can not remove your inline style then use Important

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1920px) {
        .edu_table{
             width:700px !important;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline) to [put media queries in style attributes](http://jsfiddle.net/ohyx00cu/).

target the class with the css:

```
.edu-table {
    width: 500px;
    /* styles */
}
```

Then over-ride them when the screen is 1920px or wider:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
    .edu-table {
        width: 700px;
        /* any other styles for 1920px and above */
    }
}
```

Using `min-width` in the media query will ensure the styles only apply to screens wider than 1920px.

Also, remove the inline styles as they will over-ride the css. You could use `!important` but only if you have no other conceivable option, as it is a nightmare to over-ride and can make a real mess of stylesheets.