# Uploaded responsive background-images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, amazon-s3, paperclip, background-image

I have created a RoR based app/website where the client can upload their own background image to the cover page.

Everything works well with one image, but I would like the site to be responsive and allow my client the choice to upload 3 completely separate images that are displayed depending on the px width of the window.

Currently I have the following code (only showing relevant code), which works fine:

In covers_controller.rb:

```
class CoversController < ApplicationController

 #
 @covers = Cover.all
 @cover = Cover.find_by(:published => 'yes')
 #

end
```

In application.html.erb:

```
<body style="background-image: url(<%= @cover.image %>)">
```

I have however not succeeded in making the cover images responsive. I have tried the following...

Adding a css.erb file with the following code:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .cover-bg {
    background-image: url(<%= @cover.image %>)
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .cover-bg {
    background-image: url(<%= @cover.m-image %>)
  }

}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .cover-bg {
    background-image: url(<%= @cover.lg-image %>)
  }

}
```

For the css.erb above I added two new images to the Model called m-image and lg-image (using paperclip), and added the .cover-bg class to the body tag on application.html.erb, but got a blank page.

UPDATE: here is the model. I realize that I did not add the new images to the Model. However, when first testing the idea of using css.erb, I used images from three different Models for the different @media css, and encountered the same problem:

```
class Cover < ActiveRecord::Base

      has_attached_file :image, 
        styles: { xlarge: "1600x1600>", large: "600x600>", medium: "300x300>", thumb: "100x100>" }

      validates_attachment_content_type :image,
        content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

end
```

I hope there is a easy solution out there, but I have yet to find it. I also tried various application helper methods, but no luck thus far.

Comment: Could you provide content of your model, where you have integrated paperclip ?

Comment: I realize that I did not update the model with the new images, added above:

Answer (score 1):

Your `.css.erb` file won't work because you're calling instance-dependent objects, when in likelihood, this file will be precompiled - making it static.

> how do you propose that `application.css` will be able to read `@cover`?

--

The reason why it worked when you used `<body style="...">` is because when you have an inline style in the *view*, Rails has access to all the data for the instance information etc.

To fix the problem, you need to reference your media queries in a place where you'll have access to all the instance data, namely the view.

After looking at [some resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline), it's my opinion that you're best putting it into the `<head>` of the *layout* of your app:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<head>
   <%= if [[conditional for page]] %>
      <style>
         @media (max-width: 767px) {
            .cover-bg {
               background-image: url(<%= @cover.image.url %>)
            }
         }

         @media (min-width: 768px) {
           .cover-bg {
              background-image: url(<%= @cover.image.url(:medium) %>)
           }
         } 

        @media (min-width: 1200px) {
           .cover-bg {
             background-image: url(<%= @cover.image.url(:large) %>)
           }
        }
      </style>
   <% end %>
</head>
<body class="cover-bg">
...
```

This should give you the ability to assign the custom background image size.

--

Another thing you'll want to look at is [`background-size: cover`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp):

```
#app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
.cover-bg {
   background-size: cover;
}
```

This would have to be accompanied by the inline "background-image" style, but if it was done correctly, would allow you to resize your screen and be impervious to the change of background size.

---

**Update**

Ruby on Rails applications are dynamic by nature -- they connect to a database etc.

Each time you send a request to a Rails application, there is a lot which happens on the server (you can read more about how it works with [`MVC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)):

[image]

In short, Rails basically acts like a drive-thru where you pull up, send your request/order, and then Rails comes back with the goods. The "goods" are rendered HTML code which your browser then outputs on the screen.

This rendered HTML - although will be interspersed with `@instance_variables` etc in the backend - will be *static* for the browser.

Your browser is nothing more than an engine to render HTML/CSS/JS. Rails "compiles" your data and sends back an HTML file so that `Chrome` / `Firefox` can output something useful on screen.

In other words, your `<%= @instance_variable %>` is ONLY available in the "backend" of the app (when your "order" is being processed). This means that if you're looking to make your application versatile, you *have* to make sure all backend data is available to the parts of the app which are returned to the browser each time.

As such, your CSS has a problem. By its nature, CSS is *static*. There is no reason to include it in the expensive process of repopulating with each request/order. Kind of like changing the design on the drive-thru bags each time. You do it once and then use them for several years (the bags are NOT personalized with professional print each time).

So they're kept static -- [`precompiled`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets) ([minified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming))) so that it can be downloaded *once* and then kept in the cache whilst the user browses.

If you need to make your CSS variable (IE it uses backend data), you *can* include it only if it's available before the files are precompiled. If you're trying to access instance variables, it has to be kept in the views/layout.

Comment: Thanks Rich, looks promising, will try it out. New to ruby so it's great to learn something new. So if I understand you correctly, any ruby code in a css file will be precompiled and hence static? ..more or less? I am actually alreday styling the image with a separate css class, I removed it from the example to keep the focus on the problem at hand.