# Inline CSS for mobiles

Tags: html, css, mobile

is it possible to write CSS inline code for mobile versions and how?

Something like this:

```
<div style="...code for mobile version..."> My Div </div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline

Comment: You can't inline if you are wanting to use `MEDIA` --> something like `@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {`

Comment: AND as far as I have researched .. I have found at least 3 duplicated threads here on SO ...  You should search them out before posting a new question!