# Gmail supporting media queries

Tags: android, gmail, media-queries

Google says the Gmail app should now support media queries. (https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2016/09/your-emails-optimized-for-every-screen-with-responsive-design.html)

However if I'm testing my templates on my Nexus 4 device (Gmail app version: 6.10.23.137993986.release), the support of media queries still don't seem to work. (I've updated my app today)

Are media queries still not supported, or is there something I'm missing?

Kind regards

Comment: AFAIK Gmail supports Inline CSS only. Have you tried inlining (Ouch) the queries?

Comment: I used [link](https://inliner.cm/) to make my CSS inline, this didn't put the queries inline. I don't actually think it's possible to put @media rules inline as described here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline)

Comment: Then I have no idea... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In addition on  indramurari's comment, the answer I found in the other link:**

Yes, they are rolling it out based on geo location and product.

As of October 2016, U.S.-based Gmail accounts are starting to see media query support whereas U.K.-based accounts are not. Litmus Previews use UK Gmail accounts, so we won't see the update appear in Litmus regardless of where we're testing from.

Gmail is also rolling out based on Gmail product. Here is a quick breakdown of where the rollout stands now:

[image]

[More info and updated charts on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design)