# Inline media query in email templates

Tags: html, html-email

How can I add inline media queries in style tag in inline?

```
<td class="width-33 content-cell" align="left" style="width: 33.33%; padding: 30px 0px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
```

I want to use a media query in this tag then how can I?

Answer (score 2):

No, the right way to add `@media` queries is to use them in a CSS file rather than using them as an inline styling.

Media queries need a selector to work with. The better way would be to inject a `<style></style>` tag and declare your media queries there.

Read this for reference
[Is it possible to put CSS @media rules inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline).

Comment: But when I forward this mail then that media queries were not working. so I want to add into inline

Comment: https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/media_queries_in_html_emails/ 
WIll this help?

Comment: Only a few clients support media queries, that may be a reason for why it didn't work @HemangiSatasiya

Comment: That list is 6 years old and obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

Just like Samuellawrentz said media queries are not possible inline, it has to be in `style` for it to work.

```
<style>
@media ...
</style>
```

The best and most recent collection of CSS that work in an email can be found at [campaign monitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css)'s blog.

Since you are after media queries, its supported by roughly 95% of the email clients now. Find the [most recent list here](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/media-queries/media/).

Comment: In normal email template, it's working fine but when you forward that particular email styling can't apply if it's not inline.

Comment: Forwarding will always break emails specially in Outlook as it adds it's own code before composing. You can have a forward link on emails which takes you to a page to forward to a friend or you can go with a broken email when it's forwarded. It's harsh I know but there is no way around it.