# CSS SWAP background-position for bg_image

Tags: html, css

I need to swap this code @ different browser sizes...

On 979px and below `background-position: bottom left;`

On 980px and above `background-position: bottom center;`

I need to do this inline because of certain restrictions that I am unable to change. I am using Wordpress for a company that I can not disclose but here is the code I have at the moment.

How can I swap this code for those screen sizes in CSS?

Current

```
[cs_section bg_image="_Poster.jpg" bg_color="#FBB040" class="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 40px; width: 100%; background-position: bottom left;"]
```

Need for screens below 979px

```
[cs_section bg_image="_Poster.jpg" bg_color="#FBB040" class="" style="margin: 0px; padding: 40px; width: 100%; background-position: bottom Center;"]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline maybe go for js? :( you could at least write <style> tags or not?

Comment: Thanks... I was thinking about that route however I am not advanced with js... I know how to pirate and edit some of it but I wouldn't know where to start on this ;( Any links, you can suggest, to research to get me going?