# How to have a table be a set (px) width for screen sizes above, say 1000px, but then scale down with further window size decrease?

Tags: html, html-table, datatable

```
<table id="example" class="row-border compact" style="width:1000px; table-layout:fixed;">
```

A table is set to **width:1000px** and like it to be width:1000px for screens 1000px or larger, but when the window size scales smaller I'd like the table to act as if, **width:90%**.

Is this possible with just the style description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing sounds like a [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries). Unfortunately, these aren't possible using just the inline `style` attribute on your `<table>`.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline) explains it:

> @media rules and media queries cannot exist in inline style attributes as they can only contain property: value declarations.

You could consider:

- Declaring the media queries in the `<head>` of your document.
- An external stylesheet