# HTML style="@media rule" is possible?

Tags: html

I'm in an editor, which formats the:

```
<style></style>
```

Is it possible to make the format below @media?

```
style="@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .thanks {
     color: green;
   }
}"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to put CSS @media rules inline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9808233/is-it-possible-to-put-css-media-rules-inline)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot do it inline. Instead, you would need to format it as such:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .thanks {
     color: green;
   }
}
</style>
</head>
<body class="thanks">

</body>
</html>
```