# Twiiter Follow Button For Newsletter / Html email

Tags: html, twitter, html-email, newsletter

I am codng html email where   i am required to add a  twiiter follow button such that the one who recieves    email will press follow button from  inbox and  that  will make him / her follow me on twitter   i have follwing  code

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/myanme" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false">
Follow @myname
 </a>

    <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

will it work like this or should i do something else   please help me with it ... !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML email doesn't allow javascript, so you have to do it in the url using web intents:

```
https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=CNN
```

Replace CNN with your user name.

Here is a full example:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=CNN">Follow Us</a>
```

Comment: so what will be its output ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean in the comment. Visit the url and it gives you the option to follow CNN on twitter. Replace CNN in the url with your twitter name instead. Put that in your standard `href=""` tag.

Comment: should it be  <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/user?screen_name=@CNN
">Follow us  </a> ?  will i have to add @ with CNN how does it get without that ?

Comment: Please write down  exact line i really need to do it urgently  ,

Comment: ah thats great , Thank u very much john

Answer (score 1):

I assume you got this from https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#follow.

[Generally speaking HTML readers don't allow Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message), meaning you'll just get the "Follow @myname" bare link. Your best bet is probably a static text link, a clickable image, or something fancy with CSS.