# is there any way to display jquery flip effect in emails too

Tags: jquery, gmail

I am working on a new website which sends postcards to user emails.Postcards will be displayed on the website with jquery flip effect.The front of the postcard will have a picture and the back of the card will have text message.Now i know how to make it work but i am not sure that if this effect will work in user emails or not.Please guide.

Thanks,
nkatla

Answer (score 0):

This and similar questions are quite common. Unfortunately JS and CSS in emails is both problematic (due to frustrating x-client support issues) and undesirable side effects such as security concerns.

See: [Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

And for CSS support: http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Perhaps just redirect to a normal web page and implement the card that way.