# How to display text from a url within an email using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create some javascript that will display the country from a url within an email. What it will do is grab some text from the IPInfoDB website (http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php) and display in the email. I'm using a DNN module that has a token that already grabs the IP of the sender. It looks like I need to use document.write, but not sure how to put that all together. Tried using PHP but the module doesn't allow it, and iframe but it removes this when sending through email. Any Help would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can execute JS in email.

Answer (score 1):

In theory you can include JS in emails, but it doesn't work very well, and it is badly supported.

It is not recommended to do so. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

You'd be better off loading an image from your server, and change the image depending on the IP.