# how to find the IP address of an email recipient

Tags: email, pixel, tracking

I'm wondering if it's possible, through perhaps pixel tracking or another means, to know an email recipient's IP address to provide location-based dynamic content?

Comment: I think it is difficult to realise it reliably. Images are often blocked, IP addresses can be of proxies and dynamic content is not a feature email clients are made for in the first place. Least method would be to provide a dynamic image that displays dynamic information when fetched remotely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most reliable way would likely be to embed a tiny image in the header that links to one of your servers. Then when the open the image you can get their ip address based on where it was accessed.

Comment: That is what he calls pixel tracking.

Comment: Though if the user is behind a proxy or VPN, you will get the IP address of that. "Find girls near you in No Name, Colorado".

Comment: @tripleee There is not much you can do about that.

Answer (score 2):

Pixel tracking is easy,
but you mentioned "dynamic content".

This means you need to make your email content change after the recipients open their email, which can only be achieved by javascript.

As far as I know, some email clients will block javascript execution, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message).

If you can use the first mail to record user's ip address, and store in database, you can use the information in the second mail.
Or you can provide a link in your email content, which leads the user to a dynamic webpage.

@Aviator provided a nice solution of generating dynamic image to solve the problem.