# Handlebarjs templates events

Tags: meteor, handlebars.js, html-email

In Meteor, How to get events from `handlebarjs (http://handlebarsjs.com/)` templates?
E.g. If I provide a button in handlebarjs template and sends this template in an email. Then when i click this button from email, where to set the event of button?

Comment: Is your specific problem actually related to emails? JavaScript in emails is not alway working. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message

Comment: What is the solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are used for click events on emails templates.