# It is possible to insert an interactive component into mail?

Tags: javascript, email, dynamic, outlook, interactive

I would include an interactive component into mail html code in order to insert a "widget" that permits the user to do an action.

As I saw, there's no way to execute something like Javascript into mail client (eg. Outlook). There's another way to insert an interactive component into mail?

Thanks everyone.

Comment: You asked a question in the title and then promptly answered in the second paragraph. Your first paragraph is far too vague to understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

Answer (score 0):

Mail client can't execute javascript at all.
For security reasons.

Comment: Thank you Daniele, there's no way to insert an interactive component into mail so?

Comment: Which component do you need?