# Text overflow ellipsis on two lines for email

Tags: html, css, email, templates, webkit

Is there another way to clamp text without using webkit-line-clamp? I am using it for email so it's important to not use it.

This is my current code.

```
<style>
  h2 {
    line-height:1.5rem;
    max-height:3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
  }
</style>
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</h2>
```

The problem is it's not showing ... when it's overflow. JS seems like a possible way to solve this, but it's for email so I can't use that (I have tried it and it's not working, reference :  [Is JavaScript supported in an email message?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message))

Answer (score 1):

You can not clamp text bylines in EMAIL HTML templates, only can limit text by one single line via CSS with the same code that you use and `white-space: nowrap`. This [attribute has 90.9%](https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-white-space/) of email client's support.

```
<style>
  h2 {
    line-height:1.5rem;
    max-height:3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>
```

But if you have the opportunity to edit the text manually or get the source text shorter from API or BackOffice, it would be a better option than control via CSS in this case.

Answer (score -1):

you are missing an important property of css
`white-space:nowrap`

> Sequences of whitespace will collapse into a single whitespace. Text will never wrap to the next line. The text continues on the same line until a 
>  tag is encountered

**So Your Code Will Become**

```
<style>
  h2 {
    line-height: 1.5rem;
    max-height: 3rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }
</style>
<h2>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.</h2>
```

Comment: This is for 1 line only. I need 2