# Is it possible set dark mode image in email?

Tags: javascript, email-client, darkmode

I would like not only change text-colors but also various images and icons in the emails. Is it possible/shall I use media-query as the docs say? Shall I used `display: none`, `display: block` for images, in different night-day conditions? Will the different email clients not interfere with it?

https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-dark-mode-for-email-marketers/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the way to go (using both `@media` & `[data-ogsc]`-prefixes).

> *"Will the different email clients not interfere with it?"*

The docs say:

> *"As noted above, how email clients in Dark Mode handle your regular HTML emails will vary."*

So you can't be sure if your styles will be overridden or not - that depends on the interpretation of the various and numerous mail-clients.

As the docs mention, `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)` allows you to create the most robust custom Dark Mode themes where you can implement anything from Dark Mode-specific image swaps, hover effects, background images, while `[data-ogsc]` prefixes to each CSS rule, target  specificly the Outlook app.

> *"Shall I used display: none, display: block for images, in different night-day conditions?"*

Could be an option, i.E. via getting the clients systime via JS upon openening/reading the mail..

Though be aware of:

Old clients, such as Lotus Notes, Mozilla Thunderbird, Outlook Express, and Windows Live Mail all seem to have supported some sort of JavaScript execution. Nothing else does.

It seems like a bad idea security-wise, so I would expect this to be a feature that won't always be around, even in these clients.

As stated in the accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message)

So again, you can't rely on JS being enabled/allowed in the various clients (even in message template scripts)..