# How to pass a function to href in which I create a dynamic href?

Tags: javascript, html, href

I want to pass a function to href in my a tag link but no matter what I try it doesn't work. it either leads to a 404 page or is not even clickable. What am I doing wrong?

this is not clickable

```
<body>
<a id="specialLink" href="#" onClick="redirectToApp()">click me</a>
<script>
document.getElementById('specialLink').href = redirectToApp();
function redirectToApp () {
    return "http://www.google.com";
} 
</script>
</body>
```

this is not clickable

```
<body>
<a href="#" onClick="document.location.href=redirectToApp()">click me</a>
<script>
function redirectToApp () {
    return "http://www.google.com";
} 
</script>
</body>
```

this leads to a 404 page

```
<body>
<a href="javascript:document.location.href=redirectToApp();">click me</a>
<script>
function redirectToApp () {
    return "http://www.google.com";
} 
</script>
</body>
```

I should maybe also say that I am sending this HTML via email, from which the link should be opened and unless I just pass the URL as a string to href nothing is working

Comment: Your first example simply returns a string; it doesn't know it's supposed to navigate to it. Your second and third examples are attempting to navigate to a url that includes a string that happens to be the same name as your function.
I'd use your first example, but instead of returning a url  as a string, update the location.href like you do in example #2.

Comment: First one is ok, just drop the `onClick` attribute.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for you to have a function returning the URL instead of performing the actual redirect? I mean, could you have instead `function redirectToApp() { window.location.href = 'http://www.google.com' }` and then `<a href="#" onClick="() => redirectToApp()">click me</a>`?

Comment: just add an `eventListener` and do the redirection from there instead of using a function that returns a link, kind of pointless

Comment: @secan I forgot to add that but i have tried that as well and the link is also not clickable

Comment: I don't understand why you don't use it directly `<a href="http://www.google.com">click me</a>`.

Comment: i didnt post it as its not part of the question but i am sending an email with the html and link. inside my function I will determine if the link is opened on mobile or not mobile device and based on that i add the correct href (either to my app if mobile or website if not). thats why i cant just put a static string to href.

Comment: @learncode see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054315/is-javascript-supported-in-an-email-message). One solution is to leave the url static and in the application of the url, when opened, check if is necessary to redirect to the mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
const anchor = document.getElementById('specialLink')
anchor.addEventListener((e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    window.open("https://google.com");

})
```

and remove `onClick` on the anchor tag

Answer (score 0):

With the first approach instead of using

```
<a id="specialLink" href="#" onClick="redirectToApp()">click me</a>
```

You can try out this:

```
<a id="specialLink" href="redirectToApp()" target="_blank">click me</a>
```

I have added a JS fiddle for you:
https://jsfiddle.net/26ac0x7p/2/

Comment: Its very strange but when I do exactly as you propose i open 'http://redirecttoapp%28%29/' instead. I do send the html to an email and from this email a user would open the link. im wondering if that changes things

Comment: I believe it should work in every scenario. To test your specific scenario you can send a mail to yourself and check if anything changes.

Comment: yes I do that (sending email to myself) and the link is not google but  'redirecttoapp%28%29'

Comment: That's not how HTML works. It won't run `redirectToApp()` as JavaScript to replace the `href` attribute's contents. *Maybe* if you did `href="javascript:redirectToApp()"` it *might* work, but it's horribly insecure and a horrible way of doing things. Also, don't use JSFiddle; use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552). That way the code is runnable and here on this site.