# Error while sending mail using javascript and C#

Tags: c#, .net, email

I am using the below code to send mail. I need to get output as "test123here" but im getting only test123. Can anyone help me to find out where i made mistake?

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
string mailserver = "….";
if (mailserver != "")

System.Web.Mail.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = mailserver;
mail.From = "x@test.com";
mail.To = "y@test.com";
mail.Subject = "MailSubject";
mail.UrlContentBase = "http://localhost:1900";
mail.BodyFormat = MailFormat.Html;  
string mailcontent = "<html><body>  <div>  test123<script> document.write('here');</script> </div> </body></html>";

mail.Body = mailcontent; 
SmtpMail.Send(mail);
```

Comment: You can't execute javascript in html emails (generally) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript

Comment: Unrelated closing reason.