# PHP Open Link in New Window from Gmail

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a file that sends an email to my gmail account with a Link, i want that on clicking of that link i should be able to open the result url in new window (not in new tab).

I have tried the following code with javascript but it does not works well.
It does not create's link also, please can any one tell me where i am going wrong:

```
$links ='<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">function open_mywindow(http_url){ win = window.open(http_url,"win","height=600,width=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,help=0"); win.focus();}</SCRIPT><a href="javascript:open_mywindow('http//www.google.com')">open</a>';
```

Please Help me out in this.

Code snippet will be much appreciated.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp - name should be "_blank" for new window

Comment: @x29a have you tried link you posted?

Comment: @Dexa yes, the link works and i get to the docs of "window.open()". Of course if email clients (as stated in other answers) dont execute JS, you are lost anyway.

Comment: yes so i think google will not let me do this :P

Comment: @x29a My bad, I've tried first example, didn't see second. Yes I agree changes are lost in case of email clients.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't:

- Even with JavaScript, there is no way to reliably [control if a link will open in a tab or a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-url-in-new-tab-using-javascript)
- No major email client (including the GMail web interface) will allow an [email to include JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript)

Comment: Worth mentioning: Even if you provide `_blank` value for `target` attribute, web-mail clients may override this. (_blank is probably auto-defined even if target is not set.)

Comment: @Quentin So in Short their is no way that i can do this? Right?

Answer (score 1):

Any popular Email Client like Gmail won't allow you to run the javascript code. You can however use the code `<a href="#anchorname" target="_blank">...</a>`

Comment: this open's up the link in new tab not in new window.

Comment: It all depends on settings in the useragent which decides whether to open in new windows or new tab.

Answer (score 0):

You are breaking your string at ...*dow('http//www.google.com')">o*...

Should be

```
$links ='<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript" TYPE="text/javascript">function open_mywindow(http_url){ win = window.open(http_url,"win","height=600,width=600,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,help=0"); win.focus();}</SCRIPT><a href="javascript:open_mywindow(\'http://www.google.com\')">open</a>';
```

(note the \' in url, to escape single quote which you used for php string enclousure)

You are also missing a semicolon after http in link.

Comment: sorry for the type but it still not works. Also does not creates link.