# Approving via email

Tags: javascript, email, jsonp

I would like to generate an email with two buttons approve / decline.
On clicking those buttons in the email body , make a call to my web service

I have the js written that uses jsonp to send a CORS request and am happy that works correctly

When embedding the html in the email body, it does nothing , I don't even see the button.. just text

I'm wondering is this scenario even possible or is there another route I should be taking

Comment: "uses jsonp to send a CORS request" — JSONP will never send a CORS request. There isn't really such a thing as a CORS request, although a preflight OPTIONS require might be what you are thinking of, but that is only triggered when using XMLHttpRequest.

Comment: This may be insightful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

AJAX Requests cannot be made from Email Clients. They simply don't support that kind of functionality.

Consider

- Generating two separate Web site URLs for Approve and Decline which
  show a action success message for either actions respectively.
- Or Send the URL for the page that you just created through the mail and let the ajax request take responsibility from there.