# Mandrill Template Does not accept form element

Tags: mandrill

I am trying to create a Mandrill Email Template. I want to add the following HTML to the template but the moment I save and publish the template; the form element is removed. The script is basically a stripe payment button.

```
   <form action="" method="POST">
    <script
        src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js" class="stripe-button"
    data-key="pk_test_Ufi7Z3duaDpu2GSGmuVY7Qen"
    data-amount="2000"
    data-name="Demo"
    data-description="certificatea"
    >
    </script>
    <form>
```

I have also tried to create an edit section in the template and embed html during run time , but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is addressed in [HTML email with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript) . I think Mandrill does not allow java script in email content because of security issues.