# Modal/Pop up Box in HTML Email

Tags: html, css, email, mailchimp

I am working on an HTML email, I made the HTML with many nested tables and a lot of CSS in the `<head>`

Passed it through a CSS inliner, but when I import my code into MailChimp, the modal box is not working.

I've attached the code snippet. Please advise how to have this working inside of MailChimp.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <!--[if !mso]><!-->
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title></title>
       <style type="text/css">
body {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
table {
    border-spacing: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #333333;
}
td {
    padding: 0;
}
img {
    border: 0;
}
div[style*="margin: 16px 0"] { 
    margin:0 !important;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
    -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
.webkit {
    max-width: 600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.outer {
Margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
}
.full-width-image img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 600px;
    height: auto;
}
.inner {
padding: 10px;
}
p {
    Margin: 0;
}
a {
    color: #ee6a56;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.h1 {
    font-size: 21px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-bottom: 18px;
}
.h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: bold;
    Margin-bottom: 12px;
}
 
/* One column layout */
.one-column .contents {
    text-align: left;
}
.one-column p {
    font-size: 14px;
    Margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.two-column {
text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.two-column .column {
width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.contents {
width: 100%;
}
.two-column .contents {
font-size: 14px;
    text-align: left;
}
.two-column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 280px;
    height: auto;
}
.two-column .text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.three-column {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.three-column .column {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 200px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.three-column .contents {
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
}
.three-column img {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: auto;
}
.three-column .text {
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 40%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
  padding: 35px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  background-clip: padding-box;
  text-align: center;
}

.modal {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  background: #06D85F;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.modal:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

#b1 , #b2 {
display:inline-block;
text-align: center;
margin-left: -7px;
/**other codes**/
}

.button1 {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #ff0;
  border: 2px solid #06D85F;
  border-radius: 20px/50px;
  text-decoration:none;

  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-out;
}
.button1:hover {
  background: #06D85F;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  transition: opacity 500ms;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay:target {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
  margin: 70px auto;
  padding: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
  background: #fb5050;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 30%;
  height: 30%;
  position: relative;
  transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.popup .close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  transition: all 200ms;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}
.popup .close:hover {
  color: #06D85F;
}
.popup .content {
  display: block !important;
    max-height: 60%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
  .box{
    width: 70%;
  }
  .popup{
    width: 70%;
  }
}
    </style>
    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
    <style type="text/css">
        table {border-collapse: collapse;}
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
    <center class="wrapper">
        <div class="webkit">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="600" align="center">
            <tr>
            <td>
            <![endif]-->
            <table class="outer" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="outer" align="center">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="full-width-image">
                                    <img src="Banner.jpg" width="600" alt="" />
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="one-column">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td class="inner contents">
                                    <p class="h1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
                                    <p>Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Praesent laoreet malesuada cursus. Maecenas scelerisque congue eros eu posuere. Praesent in felis ut velit pretium lobortis rhoncus ut erat.</p>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="two-column">
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="column">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner">
                                        <table class="contents">
                                             <tr>
                                                <td class="text">
                                                    Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                  <form class="box">
                                                      <a class="modal" id="b1" href="#redirect">Action </a>
                                                      <a class="modal" id="b2" href="#popup">&#94;</a> 
                                                    </form>

                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                           
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="column">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner">
                                         <table class="contents">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="1.png" width="280" alt="" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="two-column">
                   
                        <div class="column">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner">
                                         <table class="contents">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                    <img src="2.png" width="280" alt="" />
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                          
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    </table>
                    <![endif]-->
                         <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    <table width="100%">
                    <tr>
                    <td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->
                        <div class="column">
                            <table width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="inner">
                                        <table class="contents">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td class="text">
                                                    Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. 
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>
                                                  <form class="box">
                                                      <a class="modal" id="b1" href="#redirect">Action </a>
                                                      <a class="modal" id="b2" href="#popup">&#94;</a> 
                                                    </form>

                                                    <div id="popup" class="overlay">
                                                        <div class="popup">
                                                            <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>
                                                            <a class="close" href="#">&times;</a>
                                                            <div class="content"> 
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                                Maecenas sed ante pellentesque, posuere leo id, eleifend dolor. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                              
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td><td width="50%" valign="top">
                    <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                            <td bgcolor="#ee4c50" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px;">
                                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="color: #ffffff; font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
                                            &reg; asdf, efgj 2013<br/>
                                            <p>lorem</p>
                                            <p>Ipsum</p>
                                        </td>
                                        <td align="right">
                                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
                                                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                                            <img src="tw.png" alt="Twitter" width="38" height="38" style="display: block;" border="0" />
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td style="font-size: 0; line-height: 0;" width="20">&nbsp;</td>
                                                    <td style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: bold;">
                                                        <a href="http://www.twitter.com/" style="color: #ffffff;">
                                                            <img src="fb.png" alt="Facebook" width="38" height="38" style="display: block;" border="0" />
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                        
                                    </tr>
                                </table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </div>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You shouldn't use CSS in the head for emails, I believe ideally it should be all inline, with the element as `style="";`. Besides, the Bootstrap modal requires javascript to work... You don't have any links to Bootstrap files in your code, does this work on yoru computer at all? You won't be able to do this in MailChimp anyway.

Comment: Its not a bootstrap modal, Its just a css pop up kind of box does not require JS, Yes in my browser it renders perfectly well.

Answer (score 1):

The following are excerpts from the page *Limitations of HTML Email* on the mailchimp website.

> The viewing technology of a typical email client isn’t as up-to-date
>   as a web browser. Web browsers display interactive, dynamic content,
>   and they update often. But interactive elements like Flash,
>   **JavaScript**, or HTML forms won’t work in most email inboxes.

---

> **Do Not Use**
>
> The elements below are blocked by nearly all major email clients.
>   Support is either extremely limited, or nonexistent.
>
> - JavaScript
> - ...

[Limitations of HTML Email](http://kb.mailchimp.com/campaigns/design/limitations-of-html-email)

See also [HTML email with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript)

Answer (score -2):

```css
/* Full-width input fields */
input[type=text], input[type=password] {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Set a style for all buttons */
button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 14px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Extra styles for the cancel button */
.cancelbtn {
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: #f44336;
}

/* Center the image and position the close button */
.imgcontainer {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 24px 0 12px 0;
    position: relative;
}

img.avatar {
    width: 20%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}

.container {
    padding: 16px;
}

span.psw {
    float: right;
    padding-top: 16px;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    padding-top: 60px;
}

/* Modal Content/Box */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 5% auto 15% auto; /* 5% from the top, 15% from the bottom and centered */
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button (x) */
.close {
    position: absolute;
    right: 25px;
    top: 0;
    color: #000;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Add Zoom Animation */
.animate {
    -webkit-animation: animatezoom 0.6s;
    animation: animatezoom 0.6s
}

@-webkit-keyframes animatezoom {
    from {-webkit-transform: scale(0)}
    to {-webkit-transform: scale(1)}
}
    
@keyframes animatezoom {
    from {transform: scale(0)}
    to {transform: scale(1)}
}

/* Change styles for span and cancel button on extra small screens */
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
    span.psw {
       display: block;
       float: none;
    }
    .cancelbtn {
       width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Modal </title>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Modal Login Form</h2>

<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" style="width:auto;">Login</button>

<div id="id01" class="modal">
  
  <form class="modal-content animate" action="action_page.php">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
      <img src="img/img_avatar2.png" alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
    </div>

    <div class="container">
      <label><b>Username</b></label>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="uname" required>

      <label><b>Password</b></label>
      <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="psw" required>
        
      <button type="submit">Login</button>
      <input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> Remember me
    </div>

    <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
      <button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="cancelbtn">Cancel</button>
      <span class="psw">Forgot <a href="#">password?</a></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```