# Angular JS is not executing inside html content which I sent as email

Tags: java, html, angularjs, jsp

I sent html as string to email body as
message.setContent(body, "text/html");

Body contains
this output http://fireforwire.appspot.com/Rankings.html

this contains angular js script. I googled it, and found that I need to include Jquery.js before angular.js to execute in this scenario, even that is not working.

I'm getting output to email as
UserId  UserName    Points
{{ country.uservo.userId }} {{ country.uservo.userName }}   {{ country.points }}

where my angular is not executed.
Plz Plz suggest experts

codebase

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*,javax.mail.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.mail.internet.*,javax.activation.*"%>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*,javax.servlet.*"%>
<%@ page import="java.net.URLConnection,java.net.URL,org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils"%>

<% 

URL url = new URL("http://fireforwire.appspot.com/Rankings.html");
URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
String encoding = con.getContentEncoding();  // ** WRONG: should use "con.getContentType()" instead but it returns something like "text/html; charset=UTF-8" so this value must be parsed to extract the actual encoding
encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
String body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
System.out.println(body);

%>

<% 
out.println("Result: " + body + "\n");
%>
<%
String result;

Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
//props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");

Session session1 = Session.getInstance(props,
  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication("sasipudi@gmail.com", "****");
    }
  });

try {

    Message message = new MimeMessage(session1);
    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("sasipudi@gmail.com"));
    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
        InternetAddress.parse("sasipudi@gmail.com"));
    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
    message.setContent(body, "text/html");

    Transport.send(message);

    System.out.println("Done");
      result="sent succesful";

} catch (MessagingException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}


%>

<% 
out.println("Result: " + result + "\n");
%>
```

Rankings.html

```
<html>
  <head>  
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.4/angular.js"></script>

    <title>AngularJS $http Rest example</title>  
 <script type="text/javascript">
            var app = angular.module("CountryManagement", []);

            //Controller Part
            app.controller("CountryController", function($scope, $http) {


                $scope.countries = [];
                $scope.countryForm = {
                    id : -1,
                    countryName : "",
                    population : ""
                };

                //Now load the data from server
                _refreshCountryData();

                //HTTP POST/PUT methods for add/edit country 
                // with the help of id, we are going to find out whether it is put or post operation

                $scope.submitCountry = function() {

                    var method = "";
                    var url = "";
                    if ($scope.countryForm.id == -1) {
                        //Id is absent in form data, it is create new country operation
                        method = "POST";
                        url = 'rest/countries';
                    } else {
                        //Id is present in form data, it is edit country operation
                        method = "PUT";
                        url = 'rest/countries';
                    }

                    $http({
                        method : method,
                        url : url,
                        data : angular.toJson($scope.countryForm),
                        headers : {
                            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
                        }
                    }).then( _success, _error );
                };

                //HTTP DELETE- delete country by Id
                $scope.deleteCountry = function(country) {
                    $http({
                        method : 'DELETE',
                        url : 'rest/countries/' + country.id
                    }).then(_success, _error);
                };

             // In case of edit, populate form fields and assign form.id with country id
                $scope.editCountry = function(country) {

                    $scope.countryForm.countryName = country.countryName;
                    $scope.countryForm.population = country.population;
                    $scope.countryForm.id = country.id;
                };

                /* Private Methods */
                //HTTP GET- get all countries collection
                function _refreshCountryData() {
                    $http({
                        method : 'JSONP',
                         jsonpCallback: 'callback',
                         dataType: 'jsonp',     
                        url : 'http://fireforwire.appspot.com/getPoints'
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
                    //alert(response.data);
                    $scope.countries=response.data;
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(response));

                        //alert(response);
                    }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    alert("error"+response);
                        console.log(response.statusText);
                    });
                }

                function _success(response) {
                    _refreshCountryData();
                    _clearFormData()
                }

                function _error(response) {
                    console.log(response.statusText);
                }

                //Clear the form
                function _clearFormData() {
                    $scope.countryForm.id = -1;
                    $scope.countryForm.countryName = "";
                    $scope.countryForm.population = "";

                };
            });
        </script>
        <style>

.blue-button{
    background: #25A6E1;
    filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#25A6E1',endColorstr='#188BC0',GradientType=0);
    padding:3px 5px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #1A87B9
}     

.red-button{
    background: #CD5C5C;

    padding:3px 5px;
    color:#fff;
    font-family:'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    border-radius:2px;
    -moz-border-radius:2px;
    -webkit-border-radius:4px;
    border:1px solid #CD5C5C
}      

table {
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
   width: 50%;
}

caption {
  text-align: left;
  color: silver;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 5px;
}

th {
  background: SteelBlue;
  color: white;
}


tbody tr:nth-child(even) {
  background: WhiteSmoke;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align:center;
}

tbody tr td:nth-child(3),
tbody tr td:nth-child(4) {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}

tfoot {
  background: SeaGreen;
  color: white;
  text-align: right;
}

tfoot tr th:last-child {
  font-family: monospace;
}

            td,th{
                border: 1px solid gray;
                width: 25%;
                text-align: left;
                padding: 5px 10px;
            }



        </style>
    <head>
    <body ng-app="CountryManagement" ng-controller="CountryController">

        <table>
            <tr>

                <th>UserId</th>
                <th>UserName</th>
                <th>Points</th>

            </tr>

            <tr ng-repeat="country in countries.userpointsList| orderBy:'country.uservo.userId' ">

    <td> {{ country.uservo.userId }}</td>
    <td >{{ country.uservo.userName }}</td>  
    <td> {{ country.points }}</td>



            </tr>

        </table>





  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide your code please. Also know that many email services WILL block scripts.

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript) for why this won't work.

Comment: so there is no alternative?? how im gonna achieve my requirement, please suggest

Comment: You'd probably want to dynamically generate the email *before* it's sent. You would likely use a template engine such as [mustache](https://mustache.github.io/). There are plenty of other java templating engines as well, and some even have conditional templating.