# JavaScript does not work in HTML email templates

Tags: javascript, php, gmail

I need to send an email using PHP, which could be easily done using SMTP, but the challenge is to embed a web service in the HTML mail, which is why I used JavaScript in the body of the message to access the Web service when a button click is triggered.

Comment: you can use AJAX to call...

Comment: do not have form to send by Ajax but it's HTML5 plagin dom jquery example <div id="result1">10</div>
<div><?php echo $totale; ?></div>

$("#menu_plus1").click(function(){
  $calcule = 9.9 * 5;
  $("#result1").html($calcule);
  $totale = $("#result1").html($calcule);
});

Comment: share your code

Comment: It is a bad practice to add Javascript in email templates. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript)

Comment: how can i make the project function when computed and given in jquery?

Comment: Forget about using JavaScript _in_ emails … https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-lg-5 " >
                    <div class="shadow bg-white stick-to-content mb-4">

                        <div class="bg-dark dark p-4"><h5 class="mb-0">Votre commande</h5></div>


                        <div id="mainDiv">
                        <div class="bg-dark dark p-4 hide"><h5 class="mb-0">Son commande</h5></div>
                        <table class="table-cart" id="table-cart">
                            <!-- Contenu du cart list (liste de meal) -->

                               <!--  content code jquery -->
                        </table>

                        <div class="cart-summary">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-7 text-right text-muted">Order total:</div>
                                <div class="col-5"><strong class="orderTotal"></strong></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row devlieryHide">
                                <div class="col-7 text-right text-muted">Devliery:</div>
                                <div class="col-5"><strong class="devliery"></strong></div>
                            </div> 
                            <hr class="hr-sm">
                            <div class="row text-lg">
                                <div class="col-7 text-right text-muted">Total:</div>
                                <div class="col-5"><strong class="total"></strong></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-lg-7 ">
                    <form action="{{route('sendCHeckOutToMail')}}" method="post">
                         @csrf
                    <div class="bg-white p-4 p-md-5 mb-4">
                        <h4 class="border-bottom pb-4"><i class="ti ti-user mr-3 text-primary"></i>Informations de base</h4>
                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Nom:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="nom" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Prénom:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="prenom" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Ville:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="ville" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Rue et numéro:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="zip_code" class="form-control">
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Téléphone:</label>
                                <input type="text" name="phone" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>E-mail:</label>
                                <input type="email" name="mail" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <h4 class="border-bottom pb-4"><i class="ti ti-package mr-3 text-primary"></i>Livraison</h4>
                        <div class="row mb-5">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-6">
                                <label>Heure de livraison:</label>
                                <div class="select-container">
                                    <select name="date_livraison" class="form-control">
                                        <option>Aussi vite comme possible</option>
                                        <option>Dans une heure</option>
                                        <option>Dans deux heures</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg"><span>Commandez maintenant!</span></button>
                    </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </section>
```

```
<!-- Fonctions du cart Shopping -->
<script src="{{ asset('frontEnd/assets/js/js/cartShopping.js') }}"></script>
<!-- Evenements du carnet d'adresses -->
<script src="{{ asset('frontEnd/assets/js/js/events.js') }}"></script>
```