# Why sendgrid comments <script> tag of the mail body while sending the email?

Tags: javascript, sendgrid

I was trying to send an email using sendgrid api. Email had  tag which runs on clicking on a button. On receiving the email, the script gets commented on its own by sendgrid.

Code sent in email :

```
<body>
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id="demo">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
        function myFunction() {
             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        }
    </script>

</body>
```

Code received in email :

```
<body>
    <button on-click="myFunction()" id="demo">Click me</button>

    <p id="demo"></p>

    <!--script>
       function myFunction() {
         document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
        }
    </script-->

</body>
```

Note: Also see the change in onclick to on-click in  tag.

Comment: HTML emails cannot contain scripts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript - SendGrid is disabling your script to provide an additional layer of protection to your message recipients.

Comment: Agree with @Dai. Also the recipient spam filter will auto-block any e-mail containing a _script tag_, most likely causing you to be black listed as well.