# How to create a copy button using SendGrid?

Tags: html, sendgrid, sendgrid-templates

I wanna create a copy button that can copy a text to clipbord in Sendgrid , but the problem is that i can't use Javascript as i discovered lately, is there anyway to do it instead of javascript?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this (copying text to the clipboard) is with Javascript and you won't be able to embed Javascript with Sendgrid, [or any email for that matter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088016/html-email-with-javascript).